# How to plot figure in python with multiple legends

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot my data in python using pandas with multiple legends. here slots need to be presented with different legend as second figure shows

```
table=pd.pivot_table(data,index=['SDATE','Subrack','Slot'],values='VS.DSP.UsagePeak',aggfunc='max')
#pd.pivot_table(data,index=['Slot','Subrack','SDATE'],values='VS.DSP.UsagePeak',aggfunc='max').plot()
table.plot()
plt.ylabel("VS.DSP.UsagePeak")
plt.xticks(rotation=20, fontsize=6)
plt.xlabel("Time")
```

My data:

[image]

What I expect to have (excel example):

[image]

Comment: What are you getting now?

Answer (score 0):

Use `table.unstack(level=2).plot()`

I don't have your data, so I generated my own. It looks like this.
[image]

I have used this code -

```
table=pd.pivot_table(df,index=['City','Day','Item'],values='Sale',aggfunc='max')
table.unstack(level=2).plot()
```

Result is -

[image]

It looks quite random (and all over the place), as I have generated it using random numbers.